# How to add elements in string

Tags: python, string

How can I add some elements in the string? I wrote this code but it gives me this error:

> "frase2[i] += frase[i]
>
> IndexError: string index out of range"

My code is:

```
def copia(frase):
    i = 0
    while i < len(frase):
        frase2 = ""
        if (frase[i] >= 'a' and frase[i] <='z') or (frase[i] >= 'A' and frase[i] <= 'Z'):
            frase2[i] += frase[i]
        else:
            frase2[i] += " "
        i += 1
    return frase2


frase = getString("Inserisci frase: ")


print(copia(frase))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: just do `farse2 += ...` instead of `frase2[i] += ...`. Also, it will be better to change to `for`-loop

Comment: what is `frase` ? is it a string array ?

Comment: What is your main aim? Do you want to modify `frase2` at index `i`?

Answer (score 1):

There are *two* problems with your code. First, as already pointed out, `frase2[i] +=` has to be `frase2 += ...`, as `frase2[i]` does not exist yet. You want to append to the string as a whole, not to that particular character. Second, you set `frase2 = ""` in each iteration of the loop. Move that line before the loop starts!

Next, you could improve your code by iterating the characters directly, using a `for` loop instead of `while`, and using comparison chaining instead of those complex `and` and `or` statements:

```
def copia(frase):
    frase2 = ""
    for c in frase:
        if 'a' <= c <= 'z' or 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
            frase2 += c
        else:
            frase2 += " "
    return frase2
```

Or you could even use [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) (not entirely the same, but probably more like what you really want,  e.g. also allows for accented characters), use a ternary `a if c else b` and move the loop into a generator expression within a [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
def copia(frase):
    return ''.join(c if c.isalpha() else " " for c in frase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `frase2 += frase[i]`;

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

here is example how to add strings. [string append](https://www.journaldev.com/23689/python-string-append)

also `frase2[i]` is suppose to be `frase2` , because it just a string and not array